# How to find the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$ centered at $0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Here's a [Video](https://youtu.be/R6pD6s_iHaA) going over finding the Taylor series for
$\displaystyle\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ which is similar but not quite what I'm looking for.

I know how to find the Taylor/Maclaurin series of
$\displaystyle\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ at $c=0$; but I cannot figure out how to manipulate the Taylor series $x^n$ to fit the function of $$\frac{1}{(x-1)^2} \,\,\,\,at \,\,\,\,c=0$$
I tried the series $n(-x)^{n-1}$ but this isn't quite right.
I can't find anything online about this specific problem as only examples like the prior video pop up.

Comment: $1/(1-x)=1+x+x^{2}+...$. Just differentiate both sides.

Comment: Nah it's similar to that but it's 1/(x-1)^2 not 1/(1-x)

Comment: What's the difference between $1/(1-x)^2$ and $1/(x-1)^2$?

Comment: One has a denominator multiplied by -1 so I tried n(-x)^n-1 is this correct then? I tried and it doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: KayleeDalton, read again @JoséCarlosSantos 's comment carefully (and your own answer to it, which is wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ converges absolutely in $B_1(0)$ and use the Cauchy product to obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
&= \left( \frac{1}{1-x} \right)^2 \\
&= \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \right)^2 \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n x^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) x^n.
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh I didn't even know you could do this. Looks correct thank you so much !